# What is the main difference between cyclotron, synchrotron, and gyrosynchrotron radiation?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics

How are these various types of radiation generated? What is the main difference between them? Can someone suggest a book related to these radiations?

Comment: Is there a context to your question?  How did you come to be curious about cyclotron radiation, in an astronomical context.